# Edittext value gets duplicated

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a listView of objects each containing one EditText, I used the code from [this page](https://demonuts.com/android-listview-edittext/). My problem is that when I type something in an edittext, or when I add one to the listView, every one of them gets the same value.

This is my xml for the object : `

```
<Button
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
    android:id="@+id/row_button"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row_button"
    android:id="@+id/row_edittext"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    android:hint="@string/NomDuJoueur"/>
```

`

My object class is the same as in the webpage.

...and my GetView from the adapter:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup     parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //Log.wtf("New", "Holder");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_player, null, true);

        holder.editText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_edittext);
        holder.button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editModelArrayList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    holder.editText.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue());

    holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            try {
                editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValue(holder.editText.getText().toString());
                //Log.wtf("AAAD", Integer.toString(holder.editText.getId()));
                //Log.wtf("HNCZ", Integer.toString(position)+holder.editText.getText());
            }catch (Exception e){

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

I think this is caused by the Edittexts all having the same Id, but I wasn't able to find a way to modify their Id that would work.

Comment: Try to use `RecyclerView`. `ListView` is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your `TextChangedListener` doesn't have access to the correct position. Here's something that you can try.

Add a variable to store the position wherever your `ViewHolder` is defined:

```
class ViewHolder{
    // Just add this after wherever you're defining your 'editText' and 'button' 
    // variables for your holder
    int position;
}
```

Then, inside your `getView()`, store the position after your holder is set up:

```
if(convertView == null){
    // your holder set up
}else{
    // your holder retrieval
}

// Store the position inside the holder
holder.position = position;
```

And use the position from the holder inside your `onTextChanged()`:

```
try{
    editModelArrayList.get(holder.position).setEditTextValue(holder.editText.getText().toString());
}catch (Exception e){
}
```

Comment: thank you ! This was actually the problem, I resolved it by changing the listView to a Recycler view, and using the getAdapterPosition() method instead of this and it worked